# Continued Fraction and Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, continued-fractions

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are independent r.v. such that $P(X_i=1)=p=1-P(X_i=\epsilon_i)$, $0<\epsilon_i<1$
>
> $$Y=X_1+\frac{X_1}{X_2+\frac{X_2}{X_3+\frac{X_3}{X_4+\dots}}}$$

**1.What is the distribution of $Y$?**

**2.What is the characteristic  function of $Y$?**

**[If you have read up to this line you must go to "Added" part in the end of this post. Starting with $X_i$'s are i.i.d. would be less complicated]**

I do not know how to find these type of problem, so I had to post it. Any idea or website link would be helpful.

When I thought about it it was very easy for $X_i$'s are same, i.e.
$$Y^*=X_1+\frac{X_1}{X_1+\frac{X_1}{X_1+\frac{X_1}{X_1+\dots}}}$$

In this case $Y^*=\frac{X_1+\sqrt{X^2_1+4X_1}}{2}$, which is not very interesting.

In the end I think it will need condition on $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dots$ to $Y$ be a random variable. But these are very trivial observation.

#### What can we say about 1 and 2 and what can we say more than 1 and 2 about $Y$?

---

## Added:

As @Henry said we can think of less complicated version:

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. r.v. such that $P(X_1=1)=p=1-P(X_1=\epsilon)$, $0<\epsilon<1$

$$Y=X_1+\frac{X_1}{X_2+\frac{X_2}{X_3+\frac{X_3}{X_4+\dots}}}$$

Here we can write as follows: $Y=Y_1$. $Y_1=X_1(1+\frac{1}{Y_2})$, $Y_2=X_2(1+\frac{1}{Y_3}),\dots$

It can be easily seen that $Y_i$'s are identical but not independent. So first we should find question **1, 2** for this case.

### Added:

Some reference I found [here in Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273902/continued-fraction-of-random-variables). This may help.

Comment: If all the $\epsilon_i$ are equal then it looks as if  $Y_1 = X_1(1+\frac{1}{Y_2})$ where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have the same distribution (though not necessarily the same value)

Comment: why $Y_1$, $Y_2$ have same distributtion??

Comment: Good question: it seems to depend on whether the all the $\epsilon_i$ are equal.  If so, then you have the same expression all the way down.  If not then it may get complicated

Comment: @Henry what you are saying that is $Y^*$, as I wrote.

Comment: Not quite: your calculation for $Y^*$ presupposes that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are equal (which I think is unlikely), not that they have the same distribution

Comment: @Henry Yes, but we may concentre on the main problem.

Comment: @MANMAID You're asking for the distribution of an expression in infinitely many variables; I can't imagine that there are going to be many great answers to be had. I think it's worth trying to bite off smaller pieces of this question; even understanding how the distribution varies with $\epsilon$ in the case where all of the $\epsilon_i=\epsilon$ would be useful.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes. In "Added" part I said that. So starting with i.i.d. $X_i$ would be first step.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a complete solution, but hopefully it will give you some useful information on the problem. I'll work in the case where the $X_i$ are iid; i.e., $\epsilon_i=\epsilon$ for all $i$.

First of all, setting aside the probability $p$ for the moment, note that this question is really about compositions of two maps $M_1: t\mapsto1+\frac1t$ and $M_\epsilon: t\mapsto\epsilon(1+\frac1t)$.  Since $\frac1t$ is decreasing on $t\gt 0$, so are both of the maps $M_1, M_\epsilon$; this means that the minimum and maximum possible values satisfy $t_\min = M_\epsilon(t_\max)$ and $t_\max=M_1(t_\min)$. But these equations together yield quadratic equations for $t_\min$ and $t_\max$, with solutions $t_\min=\frac12(2\epsilon-1+\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1})$ and $t_\max = \frac1{2\epsilon}(1+\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1})$; thus, the maximal domain of the distribution is $[\frac12(2\epsilon-1+\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1}),\frac1{2\epsilon}(1+\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1})]$. For instance, when $\epsilon=\frac12$, the maximum interval of support is $[\frac{\sqrt{2}}2,1+\sqrt{2}]$.

Given this, we can see that the range of the map $M_1$ on this domain is $[1+\frac{1}{2\epsilon}(\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1}-1),\frac1{2\epsilon}(1+\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1})]$, and the range of the map $M_\epsilon$ is exactly $\epsilon$ times this, $[\frac12(2\epsilon-1+\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1}),\frac12(1+\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1})]$; e.g., when $\epsilon=\frac12$, the range of $M_1$ is $[\sqrt{2},1+\sqrt{2}]$ and the range of $M_\epsilon$ is $[\frac{\sqrt2}{2},\frac12(1+\sqrt{2})]$.

Now, notice that in this example the ranges of $M_1$ and $M_\epsilon$ are disjoint: $\frac12(1+\sqrt{2})\lt \sqrt{2}$, so there's no overlap.  In fact, this holds true in general: we have $\frac12(1+\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1})\lt1+\frac{1}{2\epsilon}(\sqrt{4\epsilon^2+1}-1)$ for all $0\lt\epsilon\lt 1$, so the maps $M_1$ and $M_\epsilon$ are disjoint on their mutual domain.  This implies that the support of the distribution is actually a Cantor set: totally disconnected, perfect, nowhere dense, etc. (With a lot of algebra you could probably find the Hausdorff dimension, but I don’t trust my algebra or my transcription skills to and from Alpha enough to get that one right.)

Since the structure of the domain is so complicated, an explicit description of *any* probability measure on the domain is going to be pretty messy.  In your case, there's an additional complication: because the maps are 'inversive' (decreasing), for any given fixed $p$ the probability is neither monotonically increasing nor monotonically decreasing on the (non-trivial) overlap of any interval with the domain. For instance, letting $D$ be the overall domain, we can see that the order(s) of iterates of the two maps $M_i$ applied to this domain are $\langle M_\epsilon(D)\lt M_1(D)\rangle$; $\langle M_\epsilon(M_1(D))\lt M_\epsilon(M_\epsilon(D)\lt M_1(M_1(D)\lt M_1(M_\epsilon(D)\rangle$; $\langle M_\epsilon(M_1(M_\epsilon(D)))$ $\lt M_\epsilon(M_1(M_1(D)))$ $\lt M_\epsilon(M_\epsilon(M_\epsilon(D)))$ $\lt M_\epsilon(M_\epsilon(M_1(D)))$ $\lt M_1(M_1(M_\epsilon(D)))$ $\lt M_1(M_1(M_1(D)))$ $\lt M_1(M_\epsilon(M_\epsilon(D)))$ $\lt M_1(M_\epsilon(M_1(D)))\rangle$; etc. Thus, the probabilities that $Y$ lies in each of the third-order intervals (listed by increasing $Y$) are $\langle p^2(1-p), p(1-p)^2,p^3, p^2(1-p),p(1-p)^2,(1-p)^3, p^2(1-p), p(1-p)^2\rangle$; for instance, letting $p=\frac13$, these are $\frac1{27}\langle2,4,1,2,4,8,2,4\rangle$. These sequences have a close relation with dragon curves, and the problem as a whole is very closely coupled to (weighted) iterated function systems; I'd encourage looking up more information on those.

(Also, it's possibly worth noting that in the 'limit' case where $\epsilon =0$ — i.e., the $X_i$ are either $0$ or $1$ — the support consists of exactly the convergents to $\phi=\frac12(1+\sqrt{5})$, and the probability of attaining the $n$th convergent is geometric, $p^n(1-p)$.  This is because any values of $X_i$ after the first zero are irrelevant.)